# Asp.net with MVC Partial view and models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have totally 5 models in my application. I have an "index.cshtml" page which has kendo panel bar. I referred each model in each kendo panel bar. So instead of doing like this now I want group all this 5 models into a single class files as "Mainmodel". Also I should pass only this model to controller. controller which in turn separate this models into 5 model.

```
public class MainModel
{
  public Model1 firstmodel{get; set;}
  public Model2 secondmodel{get; set;}
  public Model3 thirdmodel{get; set;}
  public Model4 fourthmodel{get; set;}
  public Model5 fifthtmodel{get; set;}
}
```

I want to use this "main" model in view. how to do this.??

```
    public class Model1
    {
    public string name {get; set;}
    }
   public class Model2
    {
    public string DOB{get; set;}
    }

//index.cshtml

    @model mvc.Models.MainModel

    @using (Html.Beginform("SaveData","Home"))
    {
      @html.kendo().panelbar()
      .items()
    {
      items.add()
       .content(@html.textboxfor(x=> x. /// here I did not get any properties that I have created name,DOB


    }   

 //My controller

    [httppost]
    public Actionresult SaveData(MainModel mainmodel)
    {
    retun view("Index",mainmodel);
    }
```

How to use this properties in MainModel inside index.cshtml?

Comment: Can you please share what you have done in View ?

Comment: `@html.textboxfor(x=> x.firstmodel.name)`

Answer (score 0):

What I did is separate the view to partial views, so the main view will accept (MainModel) as its model and then the partials will each accept a different model from within the (MainModel), for example:

```
//index.cshtml

    @model mvc.Models.MainModel

    @using (Html.Beginform("SaveData","Home"))
    {
      @html.kendo().panelbar()
      .items()
    {
      items.add()
       .content(@Html.Partial("firstmodelView", Model.firstmodel))
} 



    //firstmodelView.cshtml

@model Model1
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.name)
```

Comment: I am sorry it is Model.firstmodel not Model.Model1 I edited the answer

Comment: Could you please share the solution and if you found my answer helpful in anyway please vote up, thank you anyway

Comment: Your answer throws null exception. Since first time Mainmodel will be null. So it throws null exception.

Comment: Ok, **Thank you** for sharing, but the main step is to make partials so good for me for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 0):

//Main Model

//index.cshtml

```
@model mvc.Models.MainModel

@using (Html.Beginform("SaveData","Home"))
{
  @html.kendo().panelbar()
  .items()
{
  items.add()
   .content(@Html.Partial("firstmodelView", Model))
```

}

//In Partial Pages

```
@model mvc.Models.MainModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Firstmodel.Name)
```